# Add text objects to legend in MATLAB plots

Tags: matlab, text, plot, legend

I would like to add some text to a legend, regarding the text (i.e t1 variable) that I add in the figure.

Here a simple example of the plot:

```
xa = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5];
ya = rand(1,16);
plot(xa, ya,'o', [0 5], [0.5 0.5],'k--')
L = legend('values', 'average');
for ii = 1:numel(xa)
    t1=text(xa(ii)+0.02, ya(ii), ['A_{' num2str(ii) '}'], ...
            'HorizontalAlignment','left', ...
            'VerticalAlignment','middle', ...
            'FontSize', 8);
end
```

So, I would to have a third line in the legend that would say, for example, "A1 - A16". I read the documentation about `text` and I tried to use the `DisplayName` property, but I'm not able to make it works correctly.

Comment: You want to add "A1-A16" to the legend L?  Or you want to add it to a separate legend?

Comment: @AlexB I want to add it to legend `L`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is kind of a hack which might solve your problem. It's not elegant but the trick is to plot a dummy curve in white, which won't appear on the plot but to which you can still assign a legend. For example, adding `[0 0],[0 0],'w-'` in the call to plot and 'A1-A16' in the legend entry result in the following figure:

[image]

whole code:

```
clear
clc

xa = [1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 5 5 5 5];

ya = rand(1,16);

plot(xa, ya,'o', [0 5], [0.5 0.5],'k--',[0 0],[0 0],'w-')
L = legend('values', 'average', 'A1-A16');
for ii = 1:numel(xa)
    t1=text(xa(ii)+0.02, ya(ii), ['A_{' num2str(ii) '}'], ...
            'HorizontalAlignment','left', ...
            'VerticalAlignment','middle', ...
            'FontSize', 8);
end
```

It looks ok to me haha. Of course if you change the background color of the axes you need to change the color of the dummy line/plot, but it should work.
Hope that helps!

Comment: It works, but not when I save the figure as a .png (`print(gcf,'-dpng','-r200','testest.png'`). The solution should works for a saved gcf.

Comment: mhh it works fine for me when I add that line at the end. What does not work exactly?

Comment: When I look at the figure in MATLAB, there is nothing at the left of "A1-A16". However, when I save the figure to a .png, a black line is added to the left.

Comment: ok that's weird. What if you set the 'LineWidth' property of the line, in the call to plot, to something very very small like 0.001?

Comment: ok then I don't know. You could try save instead of print maybe. Or try modifying every property of the line until it works haha. Please let me know if something does work! Good luck.

Comment: @m_power so did you find a workaround for your problem?

Comment: I did find an answer. It consists in setting the LineStyle of the dummy line to 'none'. 
ahs = findall(gca,'type','line')
set(ahs(1),'LineStyle','none')

Comment: Ahh that makes sense I should have thought of that. Thanks for the feedback and for accepting my answer btw!

Answer (score 0):

You can append a new string to the legend by getting the last cell, modifying the cell and setting it back:

```
leghandle = findall(gcf, 'tag', 'legend'); 
legstr = get(leg,'String'); % or just get L
% ensure legstr is a cell, not a string
if ischar(legstr)
    legstr = mat2cell(legstr); 
end
legstr(end+1) = {'A1-A16'};
```

Comment: I tried to execute your solution after my code, replaced `leg` with `L` and it didn't work. The string is not added to the plot legend.